# Formatting a CSV for a Python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

If I have a CSV file that looks like this:

#### Name | Value 1 | Value 2

Foobar | 22558841 | 96655
Barfool | 02233144 | 3301144

How can I make it into a dictionary that looks like this:

```
dict = {
    'Foobar': {
        'Value 1': 2255841,
        'Value 2': 9665
    },
'Barfool': {
        'Value 1': 02233144,
        'Value 2': 3301144
    }
}
```

Comment: Please search before posting. There are 10000 questions like this a day. I'm sure one of them will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('test.csv', delimiter='|', index_col='Name').T.to_dict()

# {'Barfool': {'Value 1': 2233144, 'Value 2': 3301144},
#  'Foobar': {'Value 1': 22558841, 'Value 2': 96655}}
```